# Validating a deployed change-set removes it from the Deployed list

Tags: deployment, change-set, web

So does this mean that there is no longer a record of that deployment in the list? How does one move it back to the deployed list, without deploying it again?

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted. I guess there is no way to move it back to the deployed list without deploying it again, and maybe it's not that meaningful to do that anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you navigate to `Setup` > `Deploy` > `Inbound Change Sets`, you'll notice there are two lists of change sets: `Change Sets Awaiting Deployment` and `Deployed Change Sets`.

Your validated `Change Set` just moves from the latter list to the former. So you can still find it under `Change Sets Awaiting Deployment`. It is awaiting deployment, so that makes sense. You can still see its deployment history.

[image: Inbound Change Sets Screenshot]

Comment: OK thank you, although personally I'd rather this page was deployment event-centric rather than change-set-centric. It seems rather unintuitive for a deployed change-set to disappear from the deployed list if it is validated. Validating it doesn't change it's deployed status, but this behavior makes it appear as though it does.

Comment: I think they're trying to reduce clutter by grouping deployment results according to parent change set.